# Can I say Allah and his angels are in heaven by pointing my finger at up?

Tags: quran, fiqh, allah

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

I am sorry for the question. It sounds somehow weird, but I just come across a video on YouTube where a person is saying that is not right to say Allah and his angels are in heaven, because when we say that, where was Allah before he created the heaven and the earth?

I hope you can help me with references, thank you.

Wasalamu alaikum

Comment: Am sorry, but I can't provide the link due some problem on my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angels are in the (seven) heavens, and there is nothing wrong with saying they are in heaven or pointing towards the sky to indicate them. Allah says:

> And how many angels there are in the heavens whose intercession will not avail at all except [only] after Allah has permitted [it] to whom He wills and approves. (53:26)

As for Allah, it is possible to say He is above the throne which is above the creation:

> It is He who created the heavens and earth in six days and then established Himself above the Throne. He knows what penetrates into the earth and what emerges from it and what descends from the heaven and what ascends therein; and He is with you wherever you are. And Allah, of what you do, is Seeing. (57:4)

It is better to refrain from saying He is in heaven since the heavens are His creation.

But, it is possible to point up to indicate Allah. According to a narration in Sahih Bukhari:

> The Prophet then raised his hands till we saw the whiteness of his armpits, and he said thrice, "O Allah! Haven't I conveyed Your Message (to them)?" ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/51/31))